# Owl Carousel images from database as binary loads only the first image slide and then blank

Tags: jquery, vb.net, webforms, slider, owl-carousel

I am trying to make my owl carousel implementation dynamic by getting images from the database. Owl carousel loops through the items but displays first image only on page load. Then it disappears.
Here is my aspx file code:

```
    <div id="sg-carousel" class="this-carousel owl-theme" data-ride="carousel">
        <%Dim i As Integer = 1 %>
        <% For Each dataRow As Data.DataRow In Me.BindedDataTable.Rows %>
        <div class="item" data-pause="false">
          <img id="ImageRpt<%= i %>" class="owl-lazy" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<%= Convert.ToBase64String(CType(dataRow("Data"), Byte()))%>" alt="Red Dot" />
                                    
         <%i = i + 1 %>
         </div>
         <% Next%> 
    </div>
```

And Here is my CodeBehind code:

```
Public Function BindedDataTable() As DataTable
    Try
        Dim conString As String = ObjDB.constrLocale.ToString()
        Dim query As String = "SELECT TOP 3 * FROM Images WHERE Active=1 AND ContentType = 'image/jpeg'"
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query)
        Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(conString)
            Using sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)
                Return dt

            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        
    End Try
End Function
```

This code works fine and no errors and exceptions are thrown.I have called the BindDataTable() function on page load. Image loads in src fine and the first image displays fine. But the second image and hence the others do not display only loop iterates through the items in carousel. Further my carousel code is as follows:

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
        var items = $('.item');
        if (items.length > 1){
            $("#sg-carousel").owlCarousel({
                items: 1,
                nav: true,
                navText:["<a class='carousel-control left  btn-circle pull-left' onclick='event.preventDefault();' href='#sg-carousel' data-slide='prev'><i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i></a>",
                         "<a class='carousel-control right  btn-circle pull-right' onclick='event.preventDefault();' href='#sg-carousel' data-slide='next'><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></a>"],
                loop: true,
                dots: false,
                lazyLoad: true,
                smartSpeed:900,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: '1000',
                responsive: {
                    0: {
                        items: 1
                    },
                    767: {
                        items: 1
                  
                    },
                    1080:{
                        items: 1
                    
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        });
    
    var carousel = $('#sg-carousel');
    carousel.on({

        'initialized.owl.carousel': function () {
            carousel.find('.item').show();
            carousel.find('.loading-placeholder').hide();
        }

    }).owlCarousel(options);
    $('.item').trigger('initialized.owl.carousel').show();
```

The image Ids are not duplicate and also the image src is a binary from database. See if someone can help.

Comment: Your ````items: 1,```` might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth a try, I've done something similar in a bootstrap carousel but I've used a repeater.

Code for the Carousel:

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >  
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">  
                <asp:Repeater ID="rCarousel" runat="server">  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <div class="carousel-item <%#GetActiveClass(Container.ItemIndex) %>">  
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center w-100 h-100">
                            <a href="companies?post=<%#Eval("RecordedUET")%>"><img class="img-responsive" alt="<%#Eval("RecordedUET")%>" src="<%# GetImage(Eval("Image")) %>" /></a>
                                </div>
                       </div> 
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                </asp:Repeater>  
            </div>  
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" role="button">  
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>  
            </a>  
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" role="button">  
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>  
            </a>  
        </div>
```

Code for the GetImage:

```
        public string GetImage(object img)
    {
        return "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])img);
    }
```

and then on your bind you'd just be binding the sql command to the repeater.
I'd imagine if this doesn't work it will be js related but I couldn't say.